# Dynamically change the name of a modal button in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, modal-dialog

I have a modal popup Template used for many purpose.
All works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Edge but in IE it dont reconize the variable name of button name. *[recButton]*
It seems that the problem is the []...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkeGH.png)

```
$( "#modalTemplate" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: titleNameTxt,
    minHeight: SizeMinH,
    width: SizeW,
    minWidth: SizeMinW,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        [recButton]: recFunc, // this [] don't work in IE
        "Close": function() {
            modalDialog.dialog( "close" )
        }
    }
});
modalDialog.dialog( "open" );
```

I tried some of codes shown on this forum, but nothing work.
Thank you for help
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

This post is resolved...
to change dynamically the name of buttons in the modal you can use this:

```
const buttons = {
    "Close": function() {
        modalDialog.dialog( "close" )
    }
};

buttons[recButton] = recFunc;

$( "#modalTemplate" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: titleNameTxt,
    minHeight: SizeMinH,
    width: SizeW,
    minWidth: SizeMinW,
    modal: true,
    buttons: buttons
});
```

This method woks on each browsers...
Best regards